# How can resolve Error: "Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView"  SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2007, web-part

Following error comes when creating a WebPart In sharePoint 2010 Server.

Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the user code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. at ListMenuSample.ListMenuSample.ListMenuSample.CreateChildControls() at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper.ExecuteHttpRequest(SPUserCodeWebPartHttpRequestContext webPartExecutionContext, SPUserCodeWebPartHttpResponse httpRequestResponse) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

Thanks & Regards,
Basant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the version of the assembly has been funked up

```
Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.900.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
```

Correct should be:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
```

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a type (SPGridView) that is available to full-trust solutions but not to sandbox solutions. You probably compiled your code against the full-trust version of the DLL (so no compile-time errors), but at runtime you receive this exception because the Sandbox Host runs your code against the "light" version of the DLL.

Full trust solutions are using version 14.0.0.0 of the Sharepoint DLL.

Sandbox solutions are using version 14.900.0.0 (a version that contains fewer types).