# How to get a Full Trust Proxy to use the correct SharePoint DLL?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio

I've created a Full Trust Proxy to help out a sandbox feature that needs to deploy a lot of list view web parts on activation, because full trust has access to `SPLimitedWebPartManager` and sandbox code does not.

Now I'm getting a `System.TypeLoadException` for the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` type when I try to execute my proxy:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException:
>   Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.900.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

I can see that it's referencing version 15.900.0.0, and according to [this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/52011/8992), 15.900.0.0 is the sandbox version of the SharePoint DLL, and I need to be referencing the full version, 15.0.0.0.

Also, similarly to that answer, I can see in my VS project that the reference in the project is to the 15.0.0.0 version, and my project properties show "Sandboxed Solution: False", so I am getting no compile-time errors.

How can I get my code to reference and load the correct full trust version of `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` at run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is.... (trumpet fanfare)...

**[RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg622618(v=office.14).aspx) and call the proxy operation in the correct way:**

```
string proxyAssembly = "four part assembly name";
string proxyType = "fully qualified type name";
MyProxyArgs myArgs = new MyProxyArgs("some args");
Object result = SPUtility.ExecuteRegisteredProxyOperation(proxyAssembly, proxyType, myArgs);
```

rather than the way I was doing it:

```
MyProxyArgs myArgs = new MyProxyArgs("some args");
MyProxyOperation proxy = new MyProxyOperation();
Object result = proxy.Execute(myArgs);
```

I guess that by calling it directly it was getting executed by the `SPUCWorkerProcess` process (sandbox), instead of getting handed off to the `SPUCWorkerProcessProxy` process (full trust) as it should have been.